# Need to complete my formula

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet of our clubs race rounds, with 4 races per round, and 4 rounds per series, with 2 series for the season, that are each totalled by a sum:

- F4 is round 1 total `=SUM(B4:E4)`
- V4 is series 1 total `=SUM(F4+K4+P4+U4)`
- AQ4 is series 2 total `=SUM(AA4+AF4+AK4+AP4)`
- AR4 is grand total `=SUM(V4+AQ4)`

All of these work, but I need to calculate for the grand total minus the 2x worst scoring rounds as the championship is scored on your best 6 rounds.

The formula I have so far is:

```
=SUM(F4+K4+P4+U4+AA4+AF4+AK4+AP4)-SMALL(F4+K4+P4+U4+AA4+AF4+AK4+AP4,1)-SMALL(F4+K4+P4+U4+AA4+AF4+AK4+AP4,2)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Answer (score 0):

So I threw together a quick test bit of data,  What you are looking for is the following code

```
=(SUM(C11:H11)-(SMALL(C11:H11,1) + SMALL(C11:H11,2)))
```

What you are missing is brackets to keep the functions separated.  The above does this in pseudocode

```
=((Total of all races and rounds) - (( Lowest race total ) + (2nd lowest race)))
```

That should do it for you!   If you have any questions, ask below and I can modify this answer for clarity.

**Sample Datasheet w/ formulas exposed**
[image: Test Data showing function]

Comment: Thankyou muchly ill try this tonight when i get home

Comment: @SteveMcQueen  If it works for your, please mark as Answer. If not, let me know what bit I overlooked or didn't quite understand and I'll be happy to help you find the final answer.